# Why is Photoshop showing the wrong font color?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a Photoshop file where I select the text BONUSES & PROMOTIONS. It shows the color is #ffffff which is clearly not the case.

[image]

However if I press "I" and use the color picker, I get different the real color.

[image: Color picker shows different than white]

Anyone knows why my text tool show different color than the color picker ?

Comment: You might consider checking the opacity and weather you are working in RGB Mode

Comment: Can't really say without seeing if there are other layers with transparency on top of that text layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please send a screen shot with your text character panel open to make sure the font color is #ffffff. Oh, nevermind, it's there on the top in your first screen shot!

Is this font layer perhaps in a folder that is set to less than 100% or with some filter? It appears that this font layer IS at 100% but it's parent might not be.

Comment: That was the issue. The parent folder was 60% opacity! Thank you :)